# Remove certain pattern in text file

Tags: bash, files, text

I've got a text file of the form

```
id="111"ABC
id="222"DEF
id="333"GHJ
```

where the count of numbers within "" varies as well as the numbers vary. Furthermore, ABC, DEF and GHJ stand for random letter chains. The count of lines may vary as well.
So the only constant is id="" with some numbers inbetween the quotation marks ""

How can the text file be edited so that in the end the follwowing remains?

```
ABC
DEF
GHJ
```

The following command seems to work

```
sed 's/.*"//' file.txt | tr -s ' '
```

In another post this was suggested for a text file and it was said that sed removes everything until the final quotation mark sign "
And tr -s ' ' compresses multiple consecutive spaces into single spaces.
But what could be done if the letter chains ABC, DEF, GHJ ... contain a quotation mark sign " ?

Comment: You could restrict the match between `"` marks to only digits ex. `s/^id="[[:digit:]]*"//` or `s/^id="[0-9]*"//`. I don't see any need for the pipe to `tr`.

Answer (score 1):

Input (`file.txt`)

```
id="111"ABC
id="222"DEF
id="333""GHJ"
```

Command and output

```
sed 's/.*[[:digit:]]"//' file.txt

ABC
DEF
"GHJ"
```

Comment: That works as well! Interesting that there are two different ways to do it, once with sed and then with cut

Comment: @X3nion Please [accept an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that solves your problem best.

Answer (score 1):

> The following command seems to work
>
> ```
> sed 's/.*"//' file.txt | tr -s ' '
> ```
>
> ... But what could be done if the letter chains ABC, DEF, GHJ ... contain a quotation mark sign " ?

`cut` works well here to print out *ranges* of fields: using double quote as the delimiter, give me fields number 3 to the end

```bsh
$ cat file.txt
id="111"ABC
id="222"DEF
id="333"GHJ
id="44"MNOP"QRST"UV

$ cut -d '"' -f 3- file.txt
ABC
DEF
GHJ
MNOP"QRST"UV
```

To write that output back to the file:

```bsh
tmp=$(mktemp)
cut -d '"' -f 3- file.txt > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file.txt
```

or install the `moreutils` package and

```bsh
cut -d '"' -f 3- file.txt | sponge file.txt
```

Comment: That works! Could you maybe explain what the parameters do?

Comment: `man cut` will explain it better.